# Рекурсивный поиск по многомерному массиву

Tags: php

Задан такой массив:

```
$items = [
    1 => [
        'value' => [],
        'sub' => [
            20 => [],
            21 => [],
            22 => [],
            ...
        ],
    ],
    2 => [],
    3 => [],
    ...
];
```

Т.е. каждый узел может содержать 2 ключа value - данные узла, либо sub - вложенные узлы.
Уровень вложенности может быть любой.

Нужно реализовать поиск по ключу узла.

Сделал так:

```
public static function find(int $key, array $tree) {
    foreach ($tree as $item_key => $item) {

        if ($item_key == $key) {
            return $item;
        }

        if (is_array($item['sub']) && !empty($item['sub'])) {
            return self::find($key, $item['sub']);
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

но почему-то не работает, не пойму в чем проблема, вроде все должно работать.

Comment: чтобы было удобнее проверять и править ваш код, желательно входные данные приводить в формате, который можно использовать - например, результат вывода var_export()

Comment: может проверять-то надо `$item['value'] == $key` ? а то фактически вы проверяете либо `"value" == $key` либо `"sub" == $key`